# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: xyz.appmaker.iiuiro: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dart

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/appName"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.LauncherActivity">
    <meta-data
        android:name="asset_statements"
        android:resource="@string/assetStatements" />


    <meta-data
        android:name="twa_generator"
        android:value="@string/generatorApp" />

    <activity android:exported="true" android:name="com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.LauncherActivity"
        android:label="@string/launcherName">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.DEFAULT_URL"
            android:value="@string/launchUrl" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.STATUS_BAR_COLOR"
            android:resource="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.NAVIGATION_BAR_COLOR"
            android:resource="@color/navigationColor" />

        <meta-data android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.SPLASH_IMAGE_DRAWABLE"
            android:resource="@drawable/splash"/>

        <meta-data android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.SPLASH_SCREEN_BACKGROUND_COLOR"
            android:resource="@color/backgroundColor"/>

        <meta-data android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.SPLASH_SCREEN_FADE_OUT_DURATION"
            android:value="@integer/splashScreenFadeOutDuration"/>

        <meta-data android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.FILE_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY"
            android:value="@string/providerAuthority"/>

        <meta-data android:name="android.app.shortcuts" android:resource="@xml/shortcuts" />

        <meta-data android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.FALLBACK_STRATEGY"
            android:value="@string/fallbackType" />

        
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="https"
                android:host="@string/hostName"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.FocusActivity" />

    <activity android:name="com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.WebViewFallbackActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />

    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="@string/providerAuthority"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
    </provider>

    <service
        android:name="com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.DelegationService"
        android:enabled="@bool/enableNotification"
        android:exported="@bool/enableNotification">



        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.TRUSTED_WEB_ACTIVITY_SERVICE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
     </service>

</application>
```

Hi this is my PWA App manifest xml code

This code is working till android 7.0

but we have upgraded to android 33sdk version but the app is crashing

(showing This Error)

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: xyz.appmaker.iiuiro, PID: 2838
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: xyz.appmaker.iiuiro: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:401)
at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivityAsUser(PendingIntent.java:484)
at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:470)
at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:434)
at androidx.browser.customtabs.CustomTabsClient.createSessionId(CustomTabsClient.java:185)
at androidx.browser.customtabs.CustomTabsClient.newSession(CustomTabsClient.java:223)
at com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.TwaLauncher$TwaCustomTabsServiceConnection.onCustomTabsServiceConnected(TwaLauncher.java:301)
at androidx.browser.customtabs.CustomTabsServiceConnection.onServiceConnected(CustomTabsServiceConnection.java:57)
at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:2188)
at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:2221)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)

Comment: Please check if you have any pending intent in the code, if yes you need to set the pending intent flag

Comment: You seem to be using Custom Tabs. Make sure you are on the latest version of the `androidx` dependency for those.

Comment: not any pending intent

Comment: please send latest version androidx dependency

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue you need to modify your manifest file.

If your app targets Android 12 or higher and contains **activities, services, or broadcast receivers that use intent filters**, you must explicitly declare the `android:exported` attribute for these app components.

You can refer to the following link for more info on this:
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported